# How do I test extension method of Nhibernate which does not return the value even after specifying return in fakeiteasy?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fakeiteasy

I have a class like below where using Fluent Nhibernate I am getting data from database

```
public class MyActualClass
{
    public MyActualClass(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public List<AnnualInformation> GetData()
    {
        using (session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())  
        {  
            var result = session.QueryOver<AnnualInformation>() 
                         .SelectList(list => list  
                                     .Select(x => x.Id)  
                                     .Select(x => x.CreationDate)  
                                     .Select(x => x.AnnualAmount)  
                                     .Select(x => x.AnnualCurrency)  
                                     .Select(() => monthlyAlias.MonthlyAmount)  
                                     .Select(() => monthlyAlias.MonthlyCurrency)  
                                     .Select(() => shareAlias.CurrentSharevalue)  
                                     .Select(() => miscAlias.MarketValueAmount)  
                                     ).Where(a => a.Id == 123456).List<AnnualInformation>();  
        }
    }
}
```

I Have written unit test case for above method like below

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ISession session;

    public MyTestClass()
    {
        sessionFactory = A.Fake<ISessionFactory>();
        session = A.Fake<ISession>();

        A.CallTo(() => sessionFactory.OpenSession()).Returns(session);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var annualDetails = 
                new AnnualInformation
                {
                    Id= 1,
                    AnnualCurrency= "string",
                    AnnualAmount= "Example"
                }
         var listOfAnnualInformation=
            new List<AnnualInformation>
            {
                annualDetails 
            };  

        A.CallTo(session.QueryOver<AnnualInformation>()).WithReturnType<IList<AnnualInformation>>().Returns(listOfAnnualInformation);
        var myInstance = new MyActualClass(sessionFactory);
        myInstance.GetData();
    }
}
```

Actually if you see below code

session.QueryOver() 
                         .SelectList(...

will return "result" in method GetData(). After that I am manipulating "result" datastructure to get Id, CreationDate, AnnualAmount, AnnualCurrency
Therefore it is very important that some value is returned from "result". My problem is the count of resulty is always 0.

I want the below line of code

A.CallTo(session.QueryOver()).WithReturnType>().Returns(listOfAnnualInformation);

to return a list with atleast one element. Now i believe i clarified my requirements

Please suggest what should be done here ?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot mock static methods with FakeItEasy, and extension methods are static methods

Comment: Yacoub, my main focus here is that why below line is not yielding me the desired result  

A.CallTo(session.QueryOver<AnnualInformation>()).Returns(listOfAnnualInformation);

Comment: Is `QueryOver` an extension method? If so, then FakeItEasy cannot control its output, AFAIK.

Comment: In the title of your question you mentioned an extension method. Which method do you mean?

Comment: Actually there are two parts to this question

1. session.QueryOver return value
2. To test extension methods like session.QueryOver<AnnualInformation>().SelectList

Comment: But what is the extension method in this case?

Comment: In this case also, if you would see above in code, you would find SelectList which is an extension method

Comment: I am maybe mistaken, but `SelectList` seems not to be an extension method. It is defined in the `IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType>` interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the new code (which still doesn't quite compile - missing `;`, `result` isn't returned from `GetData`, and if it were, the return type of `GetData` should be `IList<AnnualInformation>`, but with those changes I was able to get a test to run) I can offer some commentary:

```
A.CallTo(session.QueryOver<AnnualInformation>()).WithReturnType<IList<AnnualInformation>>()
    .Returns(listOfAnnualInformation);
```

Configures the object that comes back from calling `session.QueryOver<AnnualInformation>()`. (Note there's no lambda here, so this line actually calls `QueryOver`.)
`session` is a Fake, and so when you call `QueryOver<AnnualInformation>()` on this line, it will return a new Fake `IQueryOver`. The "WithReturnType…Returns…" configures the new Fake IQueryOver to return `listOfAnnualInformation` when any method that returns a `IList<AnnualInformation>` is called.

However, when Fakes' methods are called, unless they've been configured to do something different, they return a new object. So inside `GetData` when you call `QueryOver`, you get *a different fake `IQueryOver`*, which has not been configured at all. That's one problem.

Second problem: the call to `SelectList` will return yet another faked `IQueryOver`.

We can work around all these things:

```
var aFakeQueryOver = A.Fake<IQueryOver<AnnualInformation, AnnualInformation>>();
A.CallTo(aFakeQueryOver).WithReturnType<IQueryOver<AnnualInformation, AnnualInformation>>()
    .Returns(aFakeQueryOver);
A.CallTo(aFakeQueryOver).WithReturnType<IList<AnnualInformation>>()
    .Returns(listOfAnnualInformation);

A.CallTo((() => session.QueryOver<AnnualInformation>())).Returns(aFakeQueryOver);
```

And now the faking behaves as we want. However, all we've done is short-circuit all the logic in `GetData`, except to see that it uses the `sessionFactory` to open a session, and then `QueryOver` on that session. `SelectList` and `Where` and `List` have all been bypassed.

My usual advice in this situation is to make your data access layer as thin as possible and to integration test it. Alternatively, I've seen people suggest having NHibernate use an in-memory MySql database. Still an integration test of sorts, but at least it's more isolated.

Comment: Yes you are right the call should be 

A.CallTo(() => session.QueryOver<AnnualInformation>()).Returns(listOfAnnualInformation);

But even if i keep that, I am not getting any return value which i mentioned. listOfAnnualInformation in GetData always appears with 0 records after Queryover Call. Not sure what is happening

Comment: I added your code to a test project and started using FluentNHibernate to see if I could figure out your problem, but the test code you provided doesn't even compile (for starters, missing `;` after you declare `annualDetails`). Nor can I tell what type `listOfAnnualInformation` is - it can't be a `List`, as the return type of `QueryOver` is a `QueryOver`. Could you fill in these missing details and provide a compiling failing test that we could work with?
(Even after that, there are a lot of other QueryOver calls, so in the end we may just implement a facsimile of QueryOver…)

Comment: I have updated the code with incorporating  your suggestions. Please refer above

Comment: Thanks Blair, definitely a deserving +1 for the kind of effort you have put in. however I will try it and then will get back to you on my success :)

Comment: Ha, thanks. It may just be that the types and methods involved are not amenable to this style of testing, but I'm here to help with whatever fiddly FakeItEasy bits I can.